# How can I get a hidden QGraphicsItem in a QGraphicsLayout to give up its space?

Tags: qt

I have a QGraphicsLinearLayout with a series of QGraphicsWidgets within.  I can hide the widgets just fine, but the layout spaces out all of the remaining widgets as if the hidden ones are still visible.  How can I get the layout to use this space?

My code is something like this:

```
//scene is a QGraphicsScene*, myWidget# inherits QGraphicsWidget
scene->addItem(myWidget1);
layout->addItem(myWidget1);
scene->addItem(myWidget2);
layout->addItem(myWidget2)
scene->addItem(myWidget3);
layout->addItem(myWidget3)

//then later, I call
myWidget2->hide();
```

But although myWidget2 is now invisible, the layout is still spaced as though it were there.  How can I change that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling QGraphicsLinearLayout::invalidate() to clear any cached geometry information after hiding the widget. If that doesn't help I would assume that removing the widget from the layout (if that is feasible for you) should do it.

Comment: Invalidating the layout didn't seem to do anything, but removing the widgets from the layout works pretty well.  I'm still seeing some gaps in some conditions, but I think it's due to my own logic.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are loking for `QWidget::findChild<T>(Qstring name)`
name - an object name which can be set with QObject::setObjectName(Qstring name)
T - is a type of an object you are loking for.
so in your case code should look like:

```
MyWidget* myWidget1 = new MyWidget(this);
myWidget1->setObjectName("myWidget1");
........
MyWidget* requiredWidget=scene->findChild<MyWidget*>("myWidget1");
```